# How to append the contents of a file into another file starting from a marker?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, sed, replace

For example, file1 contains:

```
Line 1
This is another line a
and another
<BEGIN>

few more lines.
```

file2 contains:

```
/* This is a line With Special Characters */
/* Another line with @ special stuff \ ? # ! ~ */
/* and another */
```

I would like to insert file2 into file1 at the point after the < BEGIN > statement.

I tried the following sed command, but it seems to be treating the '/' and '*' as special characters.

```
TOINSERT=`cat file2`
sed "/BEGIN/ a $TOINSERT" file1 > output_file
```

However, I got an error because the $TOINSERT contains special characters.  Is there a way to escape all the contents of $TOINSERT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '/<BEGIN>/ {
    r file2
    d
}' < file1 > output_file
```

***Note:*** If you want to keep the line with `<BEGIN>` just use:

```
 sed '/<BEGIN>/r file2' < file1 > output_file
```

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ ./insertf.sh
Line 1
This is another line a
and another
/* This is a line With Special Characters */
/* Another line with @ special stuff \ ? # ! ~ */
/* and another */

few more lines.
```

Comment: consider using `sed -i` to update inplace if you have gnu sed. Note however, that this will usually 'touch' the edited file even if no actual edit is made